# Getting blocks of image with Tesseract 3.0

Tags: c++, ocr, tesseract, image-segmentation

I'm trying to get image blocks by calling the SegmentPage() function (declared in 
tesseractclass.h and defined in pagesegmain.cpp) but it returns only "text blocks"...

How I can get blocks of image too ?

Thanks for your answers.

Elian